# A variant of Turán–Kubilius inequality

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, prime-numbers, arithmetic-geometry, probabilistic-number-theory

Let $\omega(n)$ the number of distinct prime factors of $n$ (counted without multiplicity). A famous consequence of Turán–Kubilius inequality is
$$
\sum_{n\leq x}(\omega(n)-\log\log x)^2=O(x\log \log x).
$$

However, I am interested in a small variation of the previous result. Indeed, I would like to obtain a similar result to 
$$
\sum_{n\leq x}(\omega(n)-A\log\log x)^2,
$$
for some previously fixed $A\in (0,1)$ (e.g., $A=1/4$ is enough for me).

Any suggestion? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

For any real $A \neq 1$ we have
$$
\sum_{n \leq x} (\omega(n) - A \log \log x)^2 \sim (1-A)^2 x (\log \log x)^2
$$
as $x \to \infty$.  This is a consequence of the quoted result
$$
\sum_{n \leq x} (\omega(n) - \log \log x)^2 \ll x \log \log x,
$$
via the triangle inequality: the vector $(\omega(n))_{n \leq x}$
of length $\lfloor x \rfloor$ is within $O( (x\log\log x)^{1/2})$ of
$(\log \log x) \cdot {\bf 1}$, and that vector has norm 
$\lfloor x \rfloor^{1/2} \log\log x$, so its distance from
$A (\log \log x) \cdot {\bf 1}$ is
$|1-A|  \lfloor x \rfloor^{1/2} \log\log x$,
which grows faster than $(x\log\log x)^{1/2}$ for any $A \neq 1$.

Intuitively,
"$\sum_{n \leq x} (\omega(n) - \log \log x)^2 \ll x \log \log x$",
or even
"$\sum_{n \leq x} (\omega(n) - \log \log x)^2 = o(x (\log \log x)^2)$",
says that the typical $n \leq x$ has $\omega(n) = (1+o(1)) \log \log x$.
That means that typically $\omega(n)$ differs from $A \log \log x$ by
$(1-A+o(1)) \log \log x$, so the sum of the squares of the differences
grows as $(1-A)^2 x (\log \log x)^2$.

Answer (score 1):

Related:

R.L. Duncan, Some Applications of the Turan-Kubilius Inequality in *Proceedings of the American Mathematical Society* 30(1), September 1971, has proved the following:

Let $g:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, with $g(0)=0,g(1)\neq 1,$ and define $f(n)=\sum_{i=1}^rg(a_i)$ where $n=p_1^{a_1} \cdots p_r^{a_r}.$

If $g(n)=O(b^{n/2}),0<b<2,$ then
$$
\sum_{n\leq x} (f(n)-g(1) \log\log x)^2 \leq c x \log\log x.
$$

My source is Sandor and Mitrinovic, *Handbook of Number Theory*, Vol. I, Chapter V. but you can also see the first page of the paper on Jstor where the result is stated.